# 2 weeks before now in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I'm trying to get the date 2 weeks before now.

this is my get today in the format I need it function:

```
function getTodayInFormat()
    {
        var d = new Date();
        var curr_date = d.getDate();
        var curr_month = d.getMonth();
        curr_month++;
        var curr_year = d.getYear()-100;
        return "20" + curr_year + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_date ;
    }
```

Now lets say I do:

```
var today_date=getTodayInFormat();
```

How do I get two weeks before this date's date? In the same format? Thank you

Comment: That's just javascript, no jQuery.

Comment: Your code will break in 87 years

Comment: I addend JQuery because I'm open to use JQUery to achive this

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the plugin [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)? I've used it to do things like this in the past and its fantastic and easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that you can pass a date object to, and subtract two weeks from that date, and return it in whatever format you need.

```
function two_weeks_ago(date_object) {
    var two_weeks = 1209600000; // two weeks in milliseconds

    var total = date_object.getTime() - two_weeks;
    var date  = new Date(total);

    return date.getFullYear() +'/'+ (date.getMonth() + 1) +'/'+ date.getDate();
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/E9LBw/)

Comment: Nice thx and thx for the getFullYear ;) will accept in 5 mins

Comment: @AlejandroCasas - You're welcome, and note that months are zero based in javascript, so december would be 11, and january 0 etc. so you should probably add 1 to the month. It's also generally a good idea to work with date objects and not strings, and add and subtract milliseconds, as that avoids a lot of issues with calculating new months, years etc. when just subtracting 14 days.